# How do I structure a python program with a while loop

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, while-loop

Task1 : Need to write a while/for loop program to take 5 inputs of integer from user between 1 to 20 and store it in a list.

Task2 : Now print the sequence between 1 to 20 skipping all the 5 numbers which were previously provided by the user and saved in the list.

I can complete Task1 :

```
skip = []
for i in range(0,5):
    temp = int(input("Enter any number between 1 to 20 :: "))
    skip.append(temp)
```

But need help with Task2.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Task 1:
Looking at your solution please consider the following:

1. The user insert non number value as an input.
2. The user insert a number larger them 20 or smaller the 0.

Consider you are allowing duplicate user input the following code will ensure the above problem will not happen:

```
user_input_int = list()

while len(user_input_int) < 5:
    try:
        tmp_in = int(input("Enter any number between 1 to 20: "))
        if 0 < tmp_in < 20:
            user_input_int.append(tmp_in)        
        print(user_input_int)
    except ValueError as err:
        print(err)
```

** If you wish that the user will input only distinct values you can change the `list` into a `set` (don't forget to change the `append` to `add` as well). **

---

Task 2:
The solution here is not that complex, you just need to go over the number between 1-20 using the [range](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) function (you already used it in your solution), and exclude the numbers entered by the user:

```
# Starting from 1 in order to skip 0 and stop at 21 in order to print 20
for i in range(1, 21):
    if i in user_input_int:
        continue
    print(i)
```

Comment: Hello Amiram...Thank a ton...Appreciate your help...This works